# Seeking global metropolitan areas geospatial dataset

Tags: geospatial, spatial

I am looking for a current, global vector dataset of metropolitan areas. The [US Census Bureau](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2019-nation-u-s-current-metropolitan-statistical-area-micropolitan-statist) has what I am after, though only for the USA. I also see that Natural Earth has an [Urban Areas dataset](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-urban-area/), yet this is based of fairly old data for my purposes (2002-2003).

Is there a generally accepted global dataset of metropolitan areas similar to the linked US Census data, or will I need to piece together multiple datasets?